# Sharing articles with og:image meta declared, but the image is not loaded on timeline

Tags: facebook-opengraph

There is the debug for a article on my website: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fextra.globo.com%2Fnoticias%2Fbrasil%2Fprotestos-em-sao-paulo-policia-detem-20-apos-saques-lojas-restaurantes-depredados-8739208.html). And below the raw data from facebook debugger to this article:

```
{
   "id": "143663629163437",
   "url": "http://extra.globo.com/noticias/brasil/protestos-em-sao-paulo-policia-detem-20-apos-saques-lojas-restaurantes-depredados-8739208.html",
   "type": "article",
   "title": "Protestos em S\u00e3o Paulo: pol\u00edcia det\u00e9m 20 ap\u00f3s saques a lojas e restaurantes depredados",
   "locale": {
      "locale": "pt_br"
   },
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://extra.globo.com/incoming/8739207-e7c-730/w107h60-PROP/sao-paulo-noite-1.jpg",
         "width": 107,
         "height": 60
      }
   ],
   "description": "S\u00c3O PAULO - Grupos de manifestantes depredaram e saquearam lojas e restaurantes em v\u00e1rios pontos da capital paulista, durante os protestos desta ter\u00e7a-feira....",
   "site_name": "Extra Online",
   "admins": [
      {
         "id": "100000043813964"
      }
   ],
   "updated_time": "2013-06-19T15:08:26+0000",
   "created_time": "2013-06-19T03:39:10+0000",
   "application": {
      "id": "154414861355894",
      "name": "Leitura Social Extra Online",
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=154414861355894"
   },
   "is_scraped": true
}
```

apparently, there is no problem with any of those meta tags, but the image is not found or is not loaded by facebook.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The image is not loaded is one question 1.
- The image is not on the timeline is question 2.

**Question 1:**

First you need to debug your URL with meta tags includes into your page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)
The debugger will notify what is wrong in your page refers to meta tags.

**Question 2**

You need to add the `fb:explicitly_shared` as a `true` value in order to publish on timeline.